# Android : Notification not sent & shown when Icon is changed

Tags: java, android, notifications

I am working on an Android project in which I am sending out notifications whenever there is an event happening. **Unfortunately, when I change the icon of Notification to our project icon, which is a 8.4kb image, I don't get any notification.** This is especially problematic as there is no error thrown, just no notificiations are received.

When I change the image to a simple red-square, I can see the notification, but the notification is not even red colored. How can I properly set the Notification image to desired image. Thank you.

As you can see the first notification, the icon is not proper.

Screenshot :

[image]

Code :

```
  NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);

mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.defaultimage);
mBuilder.setContentTitle(subject);
mBuilder.setContentText(Html.fromHtml(text));

 if (type.equals("note")) {
                    Log.d("type","note");
                    Intent resultIntent = new Intent(getApplication(), EditNoteActivity.class);
                    resultIntent.putExtra("groupid", Long.valueOf(channelName));
                    resultIntent.putExtra("canvasid", Integer.valueOf(canvasId));
                    resultIntent.putExtra("sectionid", Integer.valueOf(sectionId));
                    resultIntent.putExtra("noteid", Integer.valueOf(noteId));

                    TaskStackBuilder stackBuilder = TaskStackBuilder.create(getApplicationContext());
                    stackBuilder.addParentStack(EditNoteActivity.class);

                    stackBuilder.addNextIntent(resultIntent);
                    PendingIntent resultPendingIntent = stackBuilder.getPendingIntent(0, PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
                    mBuilder.setContentIntent(resultPendingIntent);

                    NotificationManager mNotificationManager = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(Context.NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);

                    mNotificationManager.notify(notificationCounter, mBuilder.build());
                    notificationCounter++;
}
```

The image which I am trying to set is a PNG image, of 8kb, doesn't help setting it any way. Any help would be nice. Thank you.

*Update*

When I select the image, The ide shows the image properly as seen from the screenshot :
[image]

Even if the IDE shows it correctly, the image received in notification is not correct.

Now, when I try to add it as an asset, it shows preview very wrong. And the images generated are also wrong.

Screenshot :

[image]

As you can see, it just says the image is some gray color, but its a blue colored image.

*Aloks suggestion*

```
  NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(getApplicationContext());
                mBuilder.setAutoCancel(true);
                mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.twentynotelogo);
                Bitmap icon = BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                        R.mipmap.twentynotelogo);
                mBuilder.setLargeIcon(icon);
                mBuilder.setContentTitle(subject);
                mBuilder.setContentText(Html.fromHtml(text));
```

Comment: Are you using the png image directly from your drawable folder in Android App and setting in your notification builder method call?

Comment: @ShadabK : Yes. I tried that, and also tried getting it as Bitmap and using that Bitmap, but neither worked. It just shows the box which you see in screenshot now.

Answer (score 0):

You need to implement new specification for notification,
Need to use setLargeIcon(),together with transparent small icon.

in your case you are using setSmallIcon() only that is causing issue.
Just set both small and large icon it will work.( it is an update in lollipop)

update: if you only need to set small icon than you need to use bitmap and apply some background color

Comment: Can you elaborate on how I can do it with small icon and the image I want?

Comment: In case of small icon you need to do anything special ,just take care image should be of single color and have transparency otherwise complete image will be  affected by color filtering applied automatically by system when showing small icon in notification

Comment: Okay, I will try this now. Moment

Comment: I tried your suggestion, have also updated the main post to include the code. I received no notification when I set the large icon. The image I am trying to set is : http://postimg.org/image/et8l3v2qh/

Answer (score 0):

Try to get the image as a drawable from the Android Studio as a Notifications Icon.
Also use setLarge() Icon as well.
While selecting the resource select it is a Image asset as shown below.
[image: Notification icon generation Android Studio]

The notification icon shows in preview what it will look like based on the API levels.

For your icon you need to use it as a Transparent Icon and then import in the above method itself. Remove the blue layer from the icon then load it in the Android Studio. You will get this as shown below.
[image: Transparent Icon in Android Studio]

Then if you still want blue color in your icon you need to add background color programmatically to your NotificationCompat.Builder as

```
int notificationcolor = getResources().getColor(R.color.my_notif_color);

mBuilder.setColor(notificationcolor);
```

Comment: The preview shows a grayish image, not the actual preview. Is that normal?

Comment: Yes it is how Android Studio generates the icon, for which you will need to supply it with a suitable image, so that it inverts properly.

Comment: Okay, the assets studio created 4 images and placed them in mimmap--**** ... Can you tell me how can I access the images?

Comment: You may access them with `R.mipmap` instead of  `R.drawable`  And in your code similarly add it as follows `mBuilder.setSmallIcon(R.mipmap.filename);`

Comment: The IDE is showing the preview properly on left hand side. But the image is still a square box. Should I post screenshot or something which can be helpful?

Comment: Yes please update the post with more info on your query.

Comment: @ShadabK : Any ideas? THank you-.

Comment: As per the new Patterns in Notification icons, it states Don't
"Use color to distinguish your app from others. Notification icons should only be a white-on-transparent background image."  Please refer this link for Notification Icon Updates  on Android 5.0 "https://developer.android.com/design/patterns/notifications.html"

Comment: To be honest, I am not expert in Android, what does that even mean? Do I have to change my image? How can I proceed? THanks

Comment: You  need to use a multicolor image for large icon and single color smaller size age for small icon.

Comment: @We are Borg My Answer is updated please have a look at it. I guess it resolves your issue perfectly fine.

Comment: I will tell our designer to give such an image and will post a reply when done. Thank you. :-)